# memory map adress to function call

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, driver

TLDR:
Is it possible to map an adresspace to a function call in a kernel module?

So similar to mmap. But mmap is for userspace and will only call the functions if you access the next page.

```
   +---+---+---+---+--------------------+
   |   |   |   |   |                    |
   +-------+---+---+--------------------+
       |
       +-------------------------------------------------+
                                                         |
                                   +---------------------v----------------+
                                   | void my_driver_function(int offset); |
                                   +--------------------------------------+
```

EDIT:

## here the Long Story

### Old world

In our old world we had N Devices that where controlled by N independent device drivers. Each registers of each device where memory mapped at a location. And every driver just ioremaped the registers and controlled the hardware directly.

```
+----------------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
|  Driver A      |     |  Driver B    |   | Driver C   |   |  Driver E    |
+----------------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
     |ioremap               |ioremap          |ioremap          |ioremap
     |                      |                 |                 |
+----+-----------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
|    Device A    |     |  Device B    |   | Device C   |   |  Device E    |
|                |     |              |   |            |   |              |
+----------------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
```

### New World

In our new world we merged the device hardware. But the drivers are still separate. Due to hardware limitations, it is now necessary to mutex all access to the one new device. Also there are now some more constraints that where not there in the old world (alignment, byteorder, timing, ...). But because the drivers are independent they do not know about code or access happening in another driver. So it leads to violations of this constraints.

```
+----------------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
|  Driver A      |     |  Driver B    |   | Driver C   |   |  Driver E    |
+----------------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
     |ioremap               |ioremap          |ioremap          |ioremap
     |                      |                 |                 |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+
|                         Device A/B/C/D/E                                |
|                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### the idea

because we do not want to rework all the drivers. go through all the code and seek for every pointer that my be pointing to a hardware register to guard all this accesses by mutexes, my idea was to add a *virtual device memory*. This should be a memory area there each access will be routed to a function. This function will then perform locking and tracking and things and access to the hardware.

```
+----------------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
|  Driver A      |     |  Driver B    |   | Driver C   |   |  Driver E    |
+----------------+     +--------------+   +------------+   +--------------+
     |ioremap               |ioremap          |ioremap          |ioremap
     |                      |                 |                 |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+
|               Virtual   Device A/B/C/D/E                                |
|                                                                         |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
                       |
                       |my_mapper_function(...)
                       | /* do (un)locking, check constraints, ... */
                       |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|                      Device A/B/C/D/E                                   |
|                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### the question

is there a mechanism in the linux kernel, that allows to map every access to a specific memory region to be routed trough a function? Similar to what mmap does, but actually quite different because you cannot hook every arbitrary function to mmap. Also it will not route every request through this function but only if a request crosses a page border.

Comment: TL;DR: **No** The kernel does have an internal version of mmap, callable from a driver. _will only call the functions if you access the next page_ Huh? _i need something that will call on each byte._ I don't understand what this means. Why are you trying to map a function from within a driver to a driver function? Are you trying to do a VDSO? You should _edit_ your question and explain what your _need_ is, not the solution your trying to do. This seems like an _XY problem_: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking of moving Driver A/B/C... to UserSpace using UIO, and all these driver using same kernel space code which used to control all related devices.

```
User Space    | Driver A | Driver B | Driver C |
              |================================|
Kernel Space  |           KObject ABC          |
              |================================|
Hardware      |          Device A|B|C          |
```

Comment: that would be exactly what i need, except for that we can not move the old drivers out from kernel space without a big amount of work.

if i could access UIO maps from kernel space that would be the solution.

Comment: Are Driver A|B|C directly use read(b/w/l)? If yes, you can replace them all with custom APIs.

Comment: This is want I want to prevent. The drivers are full with pointers to the ioremaped registers. I would have to go trough thousands of lines of code and check every pointer.

Comment: If you cant modify write(b/w/l)|read(b/w/l), I guest it's impossible.